# why does "iw wlan0 scan" results in errors "Network is down (-100)" or "device or resource busy (-16)"

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, ssid

Why is "iw wlan0 scan" unstable? Sometimes it provides an output and majority of the time returns nothing and provides the "resource busy"  or "network is down" error message. I have this scan written in a shell script, is that the issue? Any other ideas on root cause/fixes?

What causes this resource busy issue? Resource busy error is always the first error of the 2 mentioned.

Comment: `device or resource busy (-16)` may be because another program requests similar operations. I can trigger the error by running `sudo watch -n 0 iw wlan0 scan` in two separate consoles. The two commands will disturb each other. Is there any daemon, a script or something that could interfere with `iw` in your case?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski How can I check this? Is there a specific command or test you need me to run?

Comment: Sorry, I know no such command. You may spot something in the output of `systemctl status` (if using `systemd`) or `ps aux`. You said the scanning command is in a shell script. Can it be you're running multiple instances of the script? Or maybe old instances leave subshells in the background that scan continuously? Or the script itself runs more than one scan at a time?

Comment: Usually the first attempt at the scan works but when the script loops the scan produces empty outputs majority of the time.

Comment: My current workaround is I run the scan on a loop of 10 attempts... usually connects on the 1st, 4th, or 5th attempt but always works by the 5th attempt. Still hoping for an explanation on this behavior

Answer (score 5):

This is to answer the part of the question concerning "network is down"

```
     iw dev wlan0 scan 
     command failed: Network is down (-100)
```

Doing an strace on the command to get a clue to the problem I saw

```
      access("/proc/net", R_OK)               = 0
      access("/proc/net/unix", R_OK)          = 0
      socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
      ioctl(4, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="wlan0", }) = 0
      close(4)                                = 0
      socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
      ioctl(4, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="wlan0", }) = 0
      close(4)                                = 0
```

which suggested that the problem arose from the state of the interface.

Now as you know, in normal operation, when a network interface has been activated and is working, you see with the now deprecated ifconfig on the third line of output

```
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
```

and for a network interface which has not beem activated, the "UP" and the "RUNNING" are not present, usually just

```
      BROADCAST MULTICAST
```

So after doing the simple

```
      ifconfig wlan0 up
```

to put the wlan0 interface in to the "up and running" state, the command

```
      iw dev wlan0 scan
```

no longer gave the error message "network is down" and did a scan of the WiFi frequencies supported by the interface device.

Sometimes error messages are more opaque than they should be.

As to why the error message "device or resource busy", this will be because some other WiFi related program is running and accessing the WiFi interface eg wpa_supplicant, hostapd, network manager, wicked, kismet, wavemon, to name but six of the numerous  possibilities, as others have correctly stated in their comments.

Comment: since `ifconfig` is the old method, I suggest using the `ip` tool which is available by default on newer ubuntus: `ip link set wlan0 up`.